# how to get two columns of a df to one dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need two columns from my big data. One is ok, the other one is not exactly a column. It's a value of a column that is in a dictionary format.

```
col1 = df.select('originaltitle')
col2 = df.select('workexperiences.title') \
         .withColumn("title", concat_ws(",",col("title")))
```

I want a data frame with `col1` and `col2`

Comment: The type of col1 is not a Spark Column it is a Dataframe and it is completly different, would you clarify what you exactly want please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing columns with data frames. Here, `col1` and `col2` are not columns but DataFrames. When you select columns or do any type of transformation on a df, the result is a new data frame.

Please read the docs [Spark SQL, DataFrames and Datasets Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#spark-sql-dataframes-and-datasets-guide).

What you want is simply selecting the 2 columns `originaltitle` and `title`:

```
df1 = df.select(col('originaltitle'), col('workexperiences.title')) \
        .withColumn("title", concat_ws(",",col("title")))
```